# Mui Grid Item Fixed Width Item Beside Fill Width Item

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, grid

I'm currently using *MUI Grid* (but **I'm open to alternate solutions**) and I want two components side by side: the right most taking up 400px of width and the left component taking up the rest.

|<------------------------------- 100% of page ------------------------------->|

|<-------------------- Fill -------------------->| |<---------- 400px ----------->|

When page width is shrunk:

|<-------------------- 100% of page -------------------->|

|<--------- Fill --------->| |<---------- 400px ----------->|

My code is currently stretching the `leftComponent` to 100% of the page and pushing the `rightComponent` below it.

```
<Grid container spacing={3}>
    <Grid item xs={12} >
        <leftComponent />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item style={{width: "400px"}}>
        <rightComponent />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All you need to do is remove the number for your `xs` value. Doing this just tells the item to have a width of auto which will just fill the space

```js
<Grid container spacing={3}>
    <Grid item xs>
        <leftComponent />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item style={{width: "400px"}}>
        <rightComponent />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Though I would recommend not using grid for this situation but using `Box` component instead as the `Grid` component is really meant to stick with the 12 columns and adding in a fixed width would break it.

Comment: Thank you! Need 15+ rep to upvote your answer. How would you implement it using Box components?

Comment: actually using `Grid` is probably fine as it automatically does a lot of the styling which would you would have to do manually. If possible I would consider trying not to have the fixed width but it depends on your design

Comment: The fixed width is an Ad component, which would distort the ad if it changes size. Not the best at styling so it's a tricky situation for me to handle. Thankfully, you fixed my current problem!